# How to add text over the image?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am developing an image editor application using Ionic, AngularJS, and Cordova.

How do I use these tools to add some text over an image?

Comment: You will need to work with canvas. Then it would also require server side.

Comment: Could you please tell some server side work flow ...  thanks

Comment: thank you dfsq i did using canvas it's working but did not use any server side code  ... Thanks a Lot ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I solved this problem with following code

Using Canvas

```
var bb = function(){
     context.drawImage(imageurl, 10, 10);
     context.font = "40pt Calibri";
     context.fillText("This is the text added", 20, 20);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider using z-index approach.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply Agile but in Z-index we can set text temporarily , I need to append the text over the image permanently because we have to share the image with the text  ....